# Moment does not get correct time when local machine time is wrong

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

When the computer have wrong time (not synchronised with standard internet time), momentjs is also return wrong time. I used moment() and moment.utc() function, but all of them have same result.

How can I get global time independently with local time ? Do I need to use external service and pass it to Moment ?

Comment: Have a look at [Changing Time Source](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/now/) section of the docs, maybe you can use it together with external service to get what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @VincenzoC. But what kind of service should I use to get correct local time in javascript? If I get that then I can easily pass it to time source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this external service is required which will get current time of given timezone. I have created API for this and got current time. This time will be pass to to moment lib.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass the correct time to moment with a external service, moment is not more than a value-added API from the native Javascript time, so it can´t see more than the time from the local machine.

To get the time from internet you can use Google time API;

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro